# link java swing

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, label

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add hyperlink in JLabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel)

How can I make a kind of html link with Java Swing ?

[image]

Thank you very much

Regards

Comment: Do you require a specific component type?

Comment: See also [Highlighting Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044694/highlighting-links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a out of box hyperlink component in Swing but you can definitely build one.

Two such implementation I am aware of :

1. http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19716.html
2. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/HyperLinkcomponent.htm