# How to show URL as a click-able URL in Table and allow them to open in default browser?

Tags: java, html, swing, url, jtable

I have Java Desktop application that displays some information in a `JTable` that may contain URLs with some text in some cells. How can I make only the URL click-able and allow the user to open it in a default browser if he/she clicks on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8045059/230513) in a custom [`TableCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor). Once selected, you can [`browse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29) the URI.

Addendum: You can use [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) for your editor component and [`addHyperlinkListener()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#addHyperlinkListener%28javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener%29) to listen for events related to the link.

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
jep.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {

    @Override
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        HyperlinkEvent.EventType type = e.getEventType();
        final URL url = e.getURL();
        if (type == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED) {
            // do desired highlighting
        } else if (type == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            // open browser
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I have two issue with that my JTable is editable and I have text with URL links in the same cell. I would like to show text as-is (as a simple text i.e. unclickable) while like to open URL in browser.

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample about displaying text as hyperlink: [HyperLink in JTable Cell](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2009/02/hyperlink-in-jtable-cell.html)

Comment: It is odd that example has the call to `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());` commented out!  I wonder what the logic is?

Comment: I don't know but one should uncomment it to launch browser

Comment: I can see the appeal of using the renderer to simulate a roll-over effect, but I think the combination of renderer & editor is more flexible. Have you run the example cited?

Comment: yes and it seems to be working as expected with roll over effect