# How to show URLs as clickable in JEditorpane and allow them to opened in default browser?

Tags: java, swing, url, jeditorpane

I have Java Desktop application that displays some information in a `JTable` that contains `URL + text` in the each cell. As I am facing difficulties to [show and open URL in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029514/how-to-show-url-as-a-click-able-url-in-table-and-allow-them-to-open-in-default-b) so I am planning to show the content of cell in `JEditorpane`. User can open the content of cell in `JEditorpane` where user can easily see and edit the content.

Again how can I make only the URL click-able and allow the user to open URL in a default browser in `JEditorpane`.

Please note:

1. `JEditorpane` pane will contain both text and URL so I need to make only URL click-able.
2. The `JEditorpane` is editable. User can edit the content.

Comment: bor better help sooner please post an http://sscce.org/ demonstate your issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show URL as a click-able URL in Table and allow them to open in default browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029514/how-to-show-url-as-a-click-able-url-in-table-and-allow-them-to-open-in-default-b)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Implement an [`HyperlinkListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/HyperlinkListener.html).  E.G. in JavaDocs for [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html).
2. Ensure the JEP is displaying HTML, has a content type of `text/html`, and is not editable.
3. On event, [`Desktop.browse(URI)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse-java.net.URI-) to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want this feature with editable JEP. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

Andrew's answer is correct. The links in editable `JEditorPane` tip is available at 
[Processing hyperlinks in editable JEditorPane with HTMLEditorKit](http://java-sl.com/tip_links_in_editable.html).

Comment: It's a lot better than my skills in 'insert any other language here'. ;)

Answer (score 5):

You might consider to use a JXTable and JXHyperlink (both in the [SwingX project](http://swingx.java.net)) - they support hyperlinks in the renderer, complete with HyperlinkAction backed by Desktop (the class mentioned by @Andrew Thompson)

forgot to mention that the appropriate renderer is installed by default for class URI, a code snippet which triggers the appropriate DeskTop action out off the box by clicking into the cell containing a URI:

```
    // quick model which returns URI class
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1) {

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return URI.class;
        }

    };
    // fill with supported uri types 
    model.addRow(new Object[]{new URI("mailto:contributor@java.net")});
    model.addRow(new Object[] {new URI("http://swingx.java.net")});
    model.addRow(new Object[] {new URI("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031371/how-to-show-url-as-a-click-able-url-in-jeditorpane-and-allow-them-to-open-in-def")});
    model.addRow(new Object[] {new URI("http://dummy.org")});
    // use in JXTable
    JXTable table = new JXTable(model);
    // that's it :-)
```

**Addendum**

overlooked your requirement of url + text - in swingx default support, the whole cell is clickable, not only the string representation of the url

Answer (score 1):

```
    javax.swing.JEditorPane jep = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();
    jep.setEditable(false);
    jep.setContentType("text/html");
    jep.addHyperlinkListener(new BrowserOpener());

    class BrowserOpener implements HyperlinkListener {    
        @Override
        public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(event.getURL().toURI());
                } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException ex) {
                    // TODO 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```