# Hyperlink event type activated error

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jeditorpane

I am trying to create a simple web browser but when i run it and hover over an URL the URL gets run even though i gave `event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED`
why does it behave like `event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED`

Here is the full Code

```
package gui;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class WebBrowser extends JFrame{
private JTextField addressbar;
private JEditorPane display;
public WebBrowser(){
    super("Sagar Browser");
    addressbar = new JTextField("Enter a URL");
    addressbar.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    load(event.getActionCommand());                     
                }
            }           
            );
    add(addressbar,BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    display = new JEditorPane();
    display.setEditable(false);
    display.addHyperlinkListener(
            new HyperlinkListener(){
                public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event){
                    if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED);
                    load(event.getURL().toString());
                }
            }
            );
    add(new JScrollPane(display),BorderLayout.CENTER);      
  }
private void load(String usertext){
    try{
        display.setPage(usertext);
        addressbar.setText(usertext);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Enter Full URL");
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    WebBrowser w = new WebBrowser();
    w.setSize(500,500);
    w.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use JavaFX?
WEBVIEW: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/WebViewSample.java.htm
JAVAFX-INSTALL: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation_2-1/javafx-installation-windows.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your listener ignores the relevant predicate. You probably meant this:

```
new HyperlinkListener(){
    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent event){
        if(event.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
            load(event.getURL().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Related examples are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9029598/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16447176/230513).

Comment: tnx...it worked and the background color is coming in blue how come?

Comment: I'm not sure; in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447176/230513), the _foreground_ color is blue.