# How to make the swing mouse event to fire when the contents of the cell is clicked not on the whitespace in the cell

Tags: java, swing, hyperlink, jtable, cell

I have a table with the cells containing data as hyperlink. And I have a mouseEvent created on each cell, whenever a mouse clicked, the hyperlink is called, eventhough the click happened on whitespace. I wanted to have the hyperlink active only on text content, not anywhere else on the whitespace in the table Cell. I could find a related scenario on c# where we have dataGridView1_CellContentClick this occurs only the mouseevent occurred on content, I want something similar to do in Java swings. Please let me know, if anybody knows.

Can you please provide me an example, if you have anywhere seen this scenario.

thanks.

Comment: What is `LinkCellRendererEditor`?

Comment: i apologies to not explain it correctly, LinkCellRendererEditor is a class implements TableCellRenderer, ListCellRenderer.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9029514/230513).